# Our first connector. Pending activation stays forever

Tags: add-on, ecl-connector

This is our first try creating and loading a connector. The status "Pending activation" lasts forever. In addition. There is a banner in the Add-Ons admin page saying *"This service is not secured. Ask your application administrator to enable authentication in the Add-on Service."*, which maybe has something to see with my problem.

Attached a screenshot

Can I have some advice on this two issues? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Good question. Thanks for checking with Tridion Stack Exchange and congrats on the Experience Space GUI extension! I know people are exploring the new framework though it's nice to see it out in the community. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"This service is not secured. Ask your application administrator to enable authentication in the Add-on Service."* is not root cause of pending state. Message is there because your add-on service is not configured to use authentication (access management service).

You add on package can be in pending state (in case it is cd extension) because your cd service that needs to use it isn't restarted after you uploaded your extension to to add on service. CD services checks and loads extensions only on startup. CM extensions should load during runtime, if your extension is for CM I would check event viewer for possible errors.

Comment: It's a CM extension. All I can see in my event view is this nice message logged every minute
-----

Unable to get object: LicenseInfo
Account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' has no permission to access the protected configuration section 'entitlement'. Contact your system administrator.

Comment: Solved. Tx. Don't really know how, but now it's installed after a long long wait time.

Comment: "Entitlement" might be related to the licensing part, perhaps? It might help to share the error with Support over the [RWS Gateway](https://gateway.sdl.com/) if you wanted to double check. Or optionally try another extension to see if the delay happens all the time.